# How can I efficiently combine two time series to alternate?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

Let's say I have two **very long** series - big and small

```
index = pd.date_range(start='1952', periods=10**6, freq='s')
big = pd.Series(np.ones(len(index))*97, index)
small = pd.Series(np.ones(len(index))*2, index)
```

What I would like to achieve is create a new series which combines `big` and `small`, alternating between their values, using `borders` to determine when to switch to the other one (e.g. there is a border every 5 sec)

```
borders = pd.date_range(start='1952', periods=len(index)/5.0, freq='5s')
```

Is there an efficient matrix-based operation combo that can be used to achieve this? I tried looking at various join, merge etc. operators in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging), but couldn't find anything offering similar logic.

I could achieve this using a for-loop, but that lasts over a minute even for a series of `len()` 10ˆ5

```
alternating = pd.Series()
for i in range(1, 100, 2):
    b0 = borders[i-1]
    b1 = borders[i]
    b2 = borders[i+1]
    sec = pd.offsets.Second(1)
    alternating = alternating.append(small[b0:b1-sec]).append(big[b1:b2-sec])
```

Sample output of `alternating.head(24)`

```
1952-01-16 00:00:00     2
1952-01-16 00:00:01     2
1952-01-16 00:00:02     2
1952-01-16 00:00:03     2
1952-01-16 00:00:04     2
1952-01-16 00:00:05    97
1952-01-16 00:00:06    97
1952-01-16 00:00:07    97
1952-01-16 00:00:08    97
1952-01-16 00:00:09    97
1952-01-16 00:00:10     2
1952-01-16 00:00:11     2
1952-01-16 00:00:12     2
1952-01-16 00:00:13     2
1952-01-16 00:00:14     2
1952-01-16 00:00:15    97
1952-01-16 00:00:16    97
1952-01-16 00:00:17    97
1952-01-16 00:00:18    97
1952-01-16 00:00:19    97
1952-01-16 00:00:20     2
1952-01-16 00:00:21     2
1952-01-16 00:00:22     2
1952-01-16 00:00:23     2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your period is a fraction of a minute, you can try something like this:

```
index = pd.date_range(start='1952', periods=10**6, freq='s')
big = pd.Series(np.ones(len(index))*97, index)
small = pd.Series(np.ones(len(index))*2, index)

alternating = big[big.index.second % 10 >= 5].combine_first(small)
```

`alternating` looks then exactly as you asked and is calculated within 150ms.

Comment: Great, this is what I needed! The weird thing is that I know these methods individually, but it's not that easy to start combining them mentally - the first thing that always comes to mind is a structural, loop-based algorithm... And to change the interval you just make the condition a bit more complex - e.g. `big.index.second / 17 % 2 == 0` for 17 sec.

Comment: BTW, noticed that you reply really fast. Is there some app you're using? I tried subscribing to some tags through stackexchange, but I only get daily e-mail digests. Is there a faster method?

Comment: 17 seconds is not a fraction of a minute, therefore this won't work as awaited (0..16, 17..33, 34..50, **51..59**, the last interval is shorter). But you can use this to calculate timedelta to some fixed datetime in total seconds or use the row number.

Comment: Yes, good spotting. what I got so far is `start = big.index[0].to_pydatetime()`and
`alternating = big[(big.index.to_pydatetime() - start).total_seconds() / 17 % 2 == 0]`, but I can't seem to find a way to map the total_seconds() call to all elements.

Comment: @kermit666, how about `big[(big.index.astype(np.int64) / 10**9) % 34 >= 17].combine_first(small)`